# How to join three tables with Django ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

My models are:

```
class Profiles(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()
    email = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'

class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    content = models.CharField()
    price = models.BigIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profiles, related_name="product_owner") # user_id

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products'

class UserFollows(models.Model):
    profile   = models.ForeignKey(Profiles, related_name='profile_following') # profile_id
    following = models.ForeignKey(Profiles, related_name='profile_is_following') # following_id

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_follows'
```

To get what I want, I would query it a raw sql query below:

```
SELECT * FROM products, users, user_follows WHERE products.user_id=users.id AND
user_follows.following_id=products.user_id AND user_follows.profile_id=12345;
```

but I need to do it with Django ORM.
I can join 'users' and 'products' tables with select_related but I have no idea how to join 'user_follows'. And I need to apply filter on a field of 'user_follows' table.
Please help!

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: I can join 'users' and 'products' tables with select_related but I have no idea how to join 'user_follows'. And I need to apply filter on a field of 'user_follows' table.

Comment: What is `12345` in `user_follows.profile_id=12345`?

Comment: It's the user id(just a random one). It's where I want to apply filtering.

Comment: Try doing UserFollows.objects.filter(profile_id=12345).select_related('profile', 'following')

Comment: @Shubhanshu How do I get fields from 'products' table with it.

Comment: Oh! I accidentally assumed that 'following' is a FK to products table. Maybe you can try doing: user_profiles = Profiles.objects.select_related('product_owner'). 
And then: for user_profile in user_profiles:
                      user_profile.profile_following.all()

Please try, and let me know.